# Proper name for the inverse of a mutivariate function w.r.t. one variable

Tags: functions

Given the function $f(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$, what is the proper name of the function $g(w,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ such that $f\big(g(w,y,z),y,z\big)=w$?